# PHP script with a long header

Tags: php, apache, header

The Apache server I work with returns a 500 error due to too large a header.

Specifically, the header is this:

```
X-Drupal-Cache-Tags: block_view config: admin_toolbar_search.settings ... ... rendered user: 123456 views_data
```

It is a header that occupies more than 9K.

Is there a way to tell Apache to accept response headers of any size?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache Module **mod_headers** to customize your header.
Try this in htaccess and have fun ;)

Doc :
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html

OR

Using PHP you can check if **header_remove** is available.

```
<?PHP
    header_remove("X-Powered-By"); 
?>
```

I found this useful link for you too
["How To Remove Unwanted HTTP Response Headers"](https://zinoui.com/blog/remove-http-response-headers)

Hope this tips help you !

Comment: No problem richirm. If my suggestion helps, mark it as useful to help others. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the Apache logs I have found this:

```
Premature end of script headers: index.php
AH01070: Error parsing script headers
AH01075: Error dispatching request to:
```

Here is the bug reported in Apache's bug tracking system:
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64919

I do not know if it is corrected.